# Can I run multiple desktop environments at once (via CTRL+ALT+F1/F2/etc.) and if so, how?

Tags: command-line, desktop-environments, virtual-terminal

I am always interested in new ways to multi-task. I have learned that you get a terminal when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>/<kbd>F3</kbd>/etc. is pressed. Is there a way to start another desktop environment in one so that I could switch between the two currently running environments? Whenever I try `sudo unity` it always crashes and says `No display` , so value will be set to `1._` Is there a way to fix this? Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this guy has you covered, https://journalxtra.com/linux/desktop/multiple-desktops-on-one-linux-pc-now-thats-greedy/.

Comment: Wow! That is just what I was looking for. It is so fun to stretch Ubuntu's boundaries! Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of running two DE (Desktop Environment) at once:

1. Use available Virtual Terminal

   This is looks more reliable but not easy if you does't learned about Linux Command.

   - Switch to CLI Interface by press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>, then run `startx` (the preferred DE, for example `startx xfce4-session`).
2. Use Xtest (A good place if you want to develop DE or want to use separated X Server instead of XWayland.) But it's kind of slow

   - Type `sudo apt install xorg-server-xnest` (If it fails type `sudo apt search xnest` and look for xnest package)
   - Run `Xnest -ac :10.0` in your terminal emulator
   - Switch to your terminal emulator and type `export DISPLAY=:10.0`
   - Run secondary DE by typing `xfce4-session` (Replace `xfce4-session` with another DE installed on your system)
   - See if the magic happens (I posted this via Firefox running in Xnest on Manjaro)