# 18.04 How to run multiple desktop environments simultaneously?

Tags: xorg, desktop-environments, i3-wm

Is it possible to run two or more different desktop environments simultaneously? My question is very similar to [Can I run multiple desktop environments at once (via CTRL+ALT+F1/F2/etc.) and if so, how?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781580/can-i-run-multiple-desktop-environments-at-once-via-ctrlaltf1-f2-etc-and-if), but that does not seem to work for Ubuntu >16.

I'd like to have the default gui using compiz as well as another gui using i3wm available at the same time for the same user.

I could successfully do this by switching to another TTY and using a different user for login, but not with the same user logged in twice.

When I switch to another TTY and use `startx $(which i3)` it starts `i3`. When I attempt to open a new terminal with `mod+<enter>`, it appears  in the default gui and not in `i3`.

If I do the same with `sudo startx [...]` it works. The only difference I see in the `Xorg` log between the two approaches is the following line is present for the non-root user:

```
VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support
```

**Update**: it is acting very strange; I found out that I can open certain programs in the i3 instance started by the same user as logged into the default gui. But it only seems to be programs that haven't been opened in the default gui. After opening `nautilus` in i3, going back to the default gui and attempting to open `nautilus` there, forces it to open another instance in `i3`. Somehow it seems that programs get "anchored" to a display instance (here default gui has DISPLAY=0 and `i3` DISPLAY=1).

Comment: as to your update: this is to be expected no? what is your ideal setup?

Comment: Ideally I would like to have two completely separate desktop environments, where I can open any program in either one of them independently, but with equal access to the files of the same user. I'm afraid after your question, that this might not make sense?

Comment: no I get it but to me it'll require you having two seperate installs of each and every program with a difference in the name for of them.

Comment: Sorry, I meant making sense in the way that my idea is not feasible. My understanding of how all of this works is quite limited, so I could believe that your suggestion is the only way to do it. The easiest option would probably be to have dedicated users for each environment instead.

Comment: oh maybe that works, yeah.