# Using multiple desktops at once on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, gnome, desktop-environments, gdm, session

My aim is to separate my working space from any other spaces while using the same computer and the same OS. When I start the operating system (Ubuntu 20.04), my desktop environment (Gnome) starts automatically. Then, when I press `Ctrl-Alt-F3` to switch to another virtual space, log in as a different user and type `sudo gdm3` or `sudo systemctl start gdm3`, then nothing apparently happens. If I enter `sudo systemctl isolate graphical` then another Gnome session starts in this virtual space, but when I try to log in, the keyboard stops working altogether, or the system simply halts until a cold reboot. Also, `startx -- :2` or `startx gdm3 -- :2` gives no desired results as a graphical interface seems to load and then immediately unload.

Can someone please clarify how exactly can one start another Gnome session in a different virtual space while using the same desktop environment in another virtual space (say, the `Ctrl-Alt-F2` one)? I know this must be possible, but how exactly is not quite clear at this point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I run multiple desktop environments at once (via CTRL+ALT+F1/F2/etc.) and if so, how?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781580/can-i-run-multiple-desktop-environments-at-once-via-ctrlaltf1-f2-etc-and-if)

Comment: @hra-ved Unfortunately that didn't help (the info in the first answer is outdated, and I had tried it already; while the 2nd answer didn't work either).